# Java - sync call inside async thenCompose

Tags: java, asynchronous, completable-future, completion-stage

Consider below code as I am not able to find better words to ask the question:

```
CompletionStage<Manager> callingAsyncFunction(int developerId) {
    return getManagerIdByDeveloperId(developerId)
           .thenCompose(id ->
             getManagerById(id, mandatoryComputationToGetManager(id)))
}
```

`mandatoryComputationToGetManager()` returns a `CompletionStage`

Now the doubt which I have is :

I wanted to call `mandatoryComputationToGetManager()` and after its computation I want `getManagerById(...)` to be called.

I know there can be one way i.e. calling `thenCompose()` first to do `mandatoryComputationToGetManager()` and then do another `thenCompose()` on previous result for `getManagerById()`. But I wanted to figure out if there is a way without piping one `thenCompose()` o/p to another by which I can hold until `mandatoryComputationToGetManager()` result is ready.

As far as I understand, in the above code `getManagerById()` will get called even if the result is not yet ready from `mandatoryComputationToGetManager()`, which I want to wait for so that once `mandatoryComputationToGetManager()` give the result `getManagerById()` should get computed asynchronously.

Comment: Doesn't `mandatoryComputationToGetManager()` require any parameter? Otherwise you could call it outside and then combine the results before calling `getmanagerById()`. Also, what are the parameters for the latter? Does it expect a `CompletionStage` or some result type? In the first case you would have to handle it inside that method, in the second case nested `thenCompose()` is the way to go.

Comment: You should try to make your question as complete as possible with the minimal information required, and describe what you have tried – see also [mcve].

Comment: Thats a good catch , mandatoryComputationToGetManager() - requires a param, I should have framed the question more clearly. And mandatoryComputationToGetManager() would expect a normal result type which would be id which got computed already by getManagerIdByDeveloperId. Nested thenCompose in the way which could be used, Thanks Didier.

Comment: Best is that you edit your question to include all the necessary info :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, we should pipe one thenCompose o/p to another, but there is a way by which we can achieve what you are trying to do.

```
  CompletionStage<String> callingAsyncFunction(int developerId) {
    return getManagerIdByDeveloperId(developerId)
        .thenCompose(id -> getManagerById(id, mandatoryComputationToGetManager()));
  }

  private CompletionStage<String> getManagerById(
      Integer id, CompletionStage<String> stringCompletionStage) {
    return stringCompletionStage.thenApply(__ -> "test");
  }

  private CompletionStage<String> mandatoryComputationToGetManager() {
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture("test");
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Rahil. Thats a pretty good idea of putting a thenApply for stringCompletionStage inside getManagerById and then I can go for further computations which I want.